# How to update my Project with my new NPM version?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

How are you all?

I'm really new at this. I'm having trouble deploying my react project. When I do it, the entire website is blank. Someone said to me that I should update my Node and my NPM. That leads me to the first question: "When I update the NPM, I'm updating Node at the same time, right?"

So I researched and found this command:

```
npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n stable
```

And I think that updated my NPM. 
Done that, I ran the GIT STATUS to see if something were modified in my project. Nothing.
But that leads me to my second question: "Cool... but now I have to update my project with my new NPM version, right?"

I tried:

```
NPM UPDATE
```

But then i checked my git status again and nothing was modified. How can I update it?

Thanks guys. I really hope I did this right.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to understand npm & node is the environment to run the projects on your computer (local). It's global and not belong to any project. So if you install or update global, it won't affect your project (specific on your working copy git) because it's the global, and only is the environment to run, you can check dependencies on your package.json file.
If you wanna update node to latest:

`sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable`

update npm to latest version: `npm install npm@latest -g`

Comment: Running the project in my computer, everything goes fine. 
But when I'm deploying at Netlify, it's appearing the blank page problem. So if I understand you correctly - the problem would be at the server. Not here? 

I DO know that Netlify wouldn't have a version problem so probably the issue is not with the NPM version, right?

Comment: So, I think you are wrong when config, so the reason is neither npm nor node version. Check your configuration or use CRA instead.